# list erase with remove_if and lambda expressions

Tags: c++, list, stl

[EDIT]
Main issue found and nothing to do with this code, but curious on thoughts as to my approach with this.

I have a tile based game. So I have a 2D array for the map, but I also have objects that have world positions. I store the objects in a list (not in the 2D map array) and when an object is not in view I want to remove that object from my list. I determine "not in view" by finding the tile the object is on from it's position and if that tile is outside the tiles I can see it's not visible to me anymore so remove it. I do all of this because this is a multiplayer game and server is streaming to me objects in tiles that I can see and the client is inserting those into this list but as I move around I no longer need those objects that are outside my view. If I go back inside their view the server knows this and will send them to me again. I'm basically making the client efficient in only keeping what is visible.

To do this deletion of objects outside my view I have the following code, however this just keeps looping even though I only have 1 object in items. What am I missing?

```
items.erase(remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(), [this, playerTile, subArrayCenter](Item e) -> bool { 
        // find out what tile this item is on based on it's position
        Vec2 tile = WorldToTile(e.entity->GetPosition());

        // if this item is outside the player view then remove it
        if (tile.y < playerTile.y - subArrayCenter || tile.y > playerTile.y + subArrayCenter || tile.x < playerTile.x - subArrayCenter || tile.x > playerTile.x + subArrayCenter)
            return true;

        return false;
    }), items.end());
```

It's returning false in my situation which is correct for where I'm moving, but I'm not sure why it's going in here more than once.

Comment: Is `items` a `std::list`? If so, the erase-remove idiom is a bad choice; use the specialized `remove_if` member function instead. Also, your lambda should take `Item` by const ref, not by value.

Comment: It is a list. Can you explain why erase-remove idiom is a bad choice? Also, I think I found out it's not doing it more than once. That part is something else in my code but interested in your other comments.

Comment: @user441521 because `std::list` has a more efficient remove_if member function